# how to convert time zone of a datetime in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column, in which datetime in text format "2022-04-12 07:09:10 UTC". I want to change this into IST time zone and  convert it into date format only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to extract the date and time then add on 5h30m. From there you can either wrap it with INT or format the column to show just the date. For the one below, I used INT, which will strip the time after it is converted.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,
   REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"UTC","")+
   TIME(5,30,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now i am only getting date. Not able to get updated time

Comment: no prob. I updated it to remove the INT. Your post said you only wanted the date format -- but removing INT will return both date and time. You may need to reformat the cell to this format.